# MongoDB Aggregation Framework Date NOW

Tags: mongodb, date, aggregation-framework

I am attempting to perform a calculation in an aggregation based on the day of the current month. For example, I want to divide the total number of transactions by the day of the month to get transactions per day.

The problem is I can't figure out how to get the current date. I see plenty of examples where it's hardcoded, but what I need is more like the MySQL NOW() function.

I've tried something like this:

```
> db.statistics.aggregate([{$project: {dayofmonth: {$dayOfMonth: Date()}}}])
{
        "errmsg" : "exception: can't convert from BSON type String to Date",
        "code" : 16006,
        "ok" : 0
}
```

But that produces the error you see.

How can I get the current day of the current month for use in an aggregation calculation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost did it. You have to write `new Date()`

```
db.statistics.aggregate([
    {$project: {dayofmonth: {$dayOfMonth: new Date()}}}
])
```

it will produce results like this:

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "statisctiId",
            "dayofmonth" : 9
        }
}
```

Comment: haha, thanks for helping me finish that off. Works like a charm.

Comment: new Date() returns an unidentified constant syntax error; is there something I'm missing?